# Jquery - get nearest TR ID by Class?

Tags: jquery

I'm using a jquery to move table rows and when I release the row I'd like to get the ID for the nearest TR which has the class `group_heading`

When the row I'm moving is released I get it's ID using:

```
var row_id = $(row).prop('id');
console.log (row_id)
```

which results in `sprint_145975`

How do I get the ID of the TR nearest to  `sprint_145975` with the class `group_heading` ?

This is the table layout.

```
<tr id="present_sprints" class="group_heading nodrag">
    <td colspan="4">LIST1</td>
</tr>
<tr id="sprint_145664" style="cursor: move;">
    <td>First round - in sprint</td>
    <td>2012-09-19</td>
    <td>2012-09-27</td>
</tr>
<tr id="sprint_145975" class="toggler_row" style="cursor: move;">
    <td>Third round</td>
    <td>2012-10-04</td>
    <td>2012-10-11</td>
</tr>
<tr id="sprint_145966" class="toggler_row" style="cursor: move;">
    <td>Release prep</td>
    <td>2012-10-20</td>
    <td>2012-10-27</td>
</tr><tr id="sprint_145665" class="toggler_row" style="cursor: move;">
    <td>Second round</td>
    <td>2012-09-28</td>
    <td>2012-10-04</td>
</tr>

<tr id="future_sprints" class="group_heading nodrag">
    <td colspan="4">Future Sprints</td>
</tr>
<tr id="sprint_145964" class="toggler_row" style="cursor: move;">
    <td>Fifth run</td>
    <td>2012-10-27</td>
    <td>2012-11-03</td>
</tr>
<tr id="sprint_145965" class="toggler_row" style="cursor: move;">
    <td>Fourth round</td>
    <td><input type="text" value="2012-10-13" <="" td="">
    </td><td>2012-10-20</td>
</tr>
```

For the example above I'd be looking to get **ID = 'present_sprints'**

If the the ID of the moved row was sprint_145965, I'd expect the ID for the nearest TR with class group_heading to be **future_sprints**

How do I do this ?

I've tried:

```
$('#sprint_145975').closest('.group_heading).prop('id);
$('#sprint_145975').closest('tr.group_heading).prop('id);
```

But that didn't work..

Thanks

Comment: by nearest what do you mean previous or next?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for `.prevAll()` instead of `.closest()`. You can use `.eq()` to get only the first one. And you should use `.attr()` instead of `.prop()`.

```js
var heading = $('#sprint_145975').prevAll('.group_heading').eq(0);
console.log( heading.attr('id') );

heading = $('#sprint_145964').prevAll('.group_heading').eq(0);
console.log( heading.attr('id') );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr id="present_sprints" class="group_heading"></tr>
  <tr id="sprint_145975"></tr>
  <tr id="future_sprints" class="group_heading"></tr>
  <tr id="sprint_145964"></tr>
</table>
```